# admin_post equivalent for guest user?

Tags: plugin-development, forms

I managed to create a view which submits data from a form to my plugin via `admin_post_*` action.

This is what I have:

```
class MyPluginClass {
    public function __construct() {
        add_action('admin_post_formsbmt', array($this, 'formSubmit'));
    }

    public function formSubmit() {
        // handle the post here
    }
}
```

Then, in the form:

```
<form method="post" action="<?=admin_url('admin-post.php')?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="formsbmt">
    [other inputs]
</form>
```

It works, but this way the user must be an admin to perform the POST request.

Is there an equivalent for guest user? I need to put this form on a public page so that anyone can submit forms.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at [admin-post.php](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.7/src/wp-admin/admin-post.php), there is a check for `wp_validate_auth_cookie()` not whether the user is an administrator. So anyone with a valid authorization cookie will trigger the 
`"admin_post_{$action}"` hook.

If the user doesn't have a valid authorization cookie, then WP will trigger
`"admin_post_nopriv_{$action}"`.

Comment: I was just writing an answer, but you beat me to it ;-) Maybe you could also mention the general action less `admin_post_nopriv` for completeness?

Comment: Well for me it works when I'm logged in and it shows a blank page when I logout and try to submit the form... Then I log back in and it works again. I've just tried binding `admin_post_nopriv_formsbmt` too and nothing changed.

Comment: Nevermind... Cache in Chrome is a pain :) Even if dev tools are open and the setting says "Disable cache (while DevTools is open)" it still caches everything up. Your solution worked after hundreds of page refreshes, thank you!